# Notice: Undefined index: myusername

Tags: php, session, authentication

i've been trying make a login page, but it always says

> "Notice: Undefined index: myusername in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\loginsession\login_success.php on line 3"

here's  checklogin.php:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");//or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name");//or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
} ?>
```

and here's login_success.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['myusername']){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

?>

Comment: `session_start();` must be top of your page

Comment: you check $_SESSION['myusername'] in login success but you set $_SESSION['username'] in checklogin

Comment: To protect against SQL injection use PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @Saty that's wrong. you need to put it before writing other headers to the browser, not necessarily at the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if($_SESSION['myusername']){
```

to

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
```

Comment: Partially correct, check for isset is correct but is it the wrong session var

Answer (score 0):

There is typo: (username x myusername)

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username']){
    header("location:main_login.php");
}
```